# Persisting the images from Docker Container to host named volume

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I'm working on a node server and deploying it with docker. I have a directory "uploads" with my project directory where all images/videos and files are stored. I want to persist the uploads folder if the container is removed and created again.

```
docker run -d --name my_container --net="host" -v uploads_storage:/../uploads my_image:latest
```

`uploads_storage` is a named volume.

`/../uploads` is the location of uploads on my container

The problem is the files are not persisting if I removed the container and start it again.

**What I need**, I want to persist all the files in the uploads directory into the host. And if the container is removed and started again, all the files from the persisted location are moved back to the container, so it's accessible from my node server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a syntax error in the specification of your volumes.
If you specify "/../uploads", the container expects this to be in the top-directory (first "/"), then one directory above (".."), but there is nothing above "/".

Below an example in docker-compose doing what you want:

- Create a container with a mapping to a directory on the Host ("./uploads") and "/uploads" in the Container
- If you remove/delete the container and start it up againg, you see the same files again.

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  shell:
    image: ubuntu:latest
    restart: "no"
    container_name: my_container
    volumes:
      - ./uploads:/uploads
    networks:
      - my_network
    command: ["sleep","3650d"]

networks:
  my_network:
    name: my_network
```

Create a directory called 'uploads' on the same level as this docker-compose.yml file

Run this with

```sh
$ docker-compose up -d
```

Create a dummy file in ./uploads on the Host:

```sh
$ echo "Hello World" > ./uploads/hello.txt
```

And go in the container:

```sh
$ docker exec -it my_container /bin/bash
```

In the container check for the file

```sh
# ls -la /uploads
```

You will see the file is there. And you can edit it on both locations: On the Host and in the Container.
It is the same file you are editing.